# Unable to check Switch cases with "null" value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, null, switch-statement

To check multiple conditions i am using `switch statements`

**code:** here all cases working fine but. **if `user_details?.rating = ""` is empty then i need to show default case i mean all stars empty but its going to `case _ where user_details?.rating ?? "" <= "1.9"` why?**

if i do force unwrap `case _ where (user_details?.rating)! <= "1.9":` then app getting crash when reach this

**user_details?.rating = "" then how to show all stars empty**

please guide me

```
switch user_details?.rating{

case "1.0":

    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")

    star2.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
break
case _ where user_details?.rating ?? "" <= "1.9":

    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "star-half")

    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
break

case "2.0":

    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "star")

    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")

 break

case _ where user_details?.rating ?? "" <= "2.9":

    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "star-half")

    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
 break


default:
    star1.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")

break

}
```

Comment: I would suggest converting `rating` to a Double and use ranges with your cases instead

Comment: When two strings are compared, their unicode value is compared. So ```"" <= "1.9"``` returns ```true```. what u can do is use an extra condition like ```user_details?.rating ?? "" <= "1.9" && user_details?.rating ?? "" != ""```

Comment: Also u can get ```let starCount = Double(user_details?.rating) ) ?? 0``` and compare it as a Double

Comment: Unrelated, but this is Swift.  No `break` statements at the end of `case`s (and no ugly snake_case names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is crashing because you are `force unwrapping` `user_details?.rating` which basically says: **This property holds a value that is not `nil`, and if I'm wrong crash the app**.

Try unwrapping `user_details?.rating` safely before the switch statement:

1. Using `if let`:

   ```
   if let rating = user_details?.rating {
   }else {
   }
   ```
2. Using `guard let`:

   ```
   guard let rating = user_details?.rating else {
       return
   }
   ```
3. Providing default value:

   ```
   let rating = user_details?.rating ?? ""
   ```

Then your code will look like:

```
guard let rating = user_details?.rating else {
    //do something if it is nil
    return
}

switch rating {
case "1.0":
    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    break
case _ where user_details?.rating ?? "" <= "1.9":
    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "star-half")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    break
case "2.0":
    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    break
case _ where user_details?.rating ?? "" <= "2.9":
    star1.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "star-half")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    break
default:
    star1.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star2.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star3.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star4.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    star5.image = UIImage(named: "staremp")
    break
}
```